# Data is lost on orientation change on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've recently been struggling with configuration changes and saving states in fragments in my app. I got some fragments to work by Overriding the onSaveInstanceState inside my fragments (which I didn't know was possible, I did this is my MainActivity before).

I'm working with one MainActivity with many fragments and currently what's happening is that when I have my Fragment1 displayed and I open a DatePickerFragment, which is a dialog displayed on the Fragment1 I loose the data that is entered in Fragment1 when I rotate the screen.

I'm already saving the state in Fragment1 by using onSaveInstanceState method and when I rotate the device when only Fragment1 is visible, no data is lost. It is only when the DatePickerFragment is created and visible and I rotate the phone, that the data is lost.

I'll give you an example:
In Fragment1 I can select a date and enter a text in two fields.
I enter "blabla" in the text field.
And now I want to enter a date, so I click on a button which opens up the DatePickerFragment, I select a Date and then I rotate my device.
I click "Set" and I view my Fragment1 where "blabla" is now gone and my text field is empty (Fragment1 didn't go through with saving state).

This is my Fragment1 code:

```
public class GoalFragment extends Fragment {
private ImageButton edit_weight, edit_date;
private ToggleButton goal_type_toggle;
private TextView mWeightValue, mDateValue;
private Button mSaveButton;
private DatePicker mDatePicker;
private Calendar calendar;
private float weight_goal;
private Date date_goal;
private int selectedConstant;
private float convertedFloat;
private boolean didSetWeight = false;
private boolean didSetDate = false;
final static int DATE_PICKER_ID = 0;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
public static Date SELECTED_DATE;
public static float SELECTED_WEIGHT;
public static boolean isLoose = true;
public static float ENTERED_WEIGHT;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goal_fragment, parent, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //Intialize view elements
    edit_weight = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_change_goal);
    edit_date = (ImageButton)   view.findViewById(R.id.button_change_goal_date);
    goal_type_toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.goal_switch);
    mWeightValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_goal_value);
    mDateValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_goal_date_value);
    mSaveButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save_goal_btn);
    mSaveButton.setEnabled(false);

    //attempt to restore data on rotation with bundle as arguments
    Bundle restoreBundle = getArguments();
    if (restoreBundle != null) {
        float restored_weight = restoreBundle.getFloat("goal_weight");
        String weight_value = Float.toString(restored_weight);
        mWeightValue.setText(weight_value);
    } else {
        initializeGoalData();
    }

    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Goal goal = new Goal(convertedFloat, SELECTED_DATE, isLoose);
            WeighInLab.get(getActivity()).createNewRealmGoal(goal);
        }
    });

    edit_weight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showWeightEditor();
        }
    });

    edit_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePicker();

        }
    });

    goal_type_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                isLoose = false;

            } else {
                isLoose = true;
            }
        }
    });


    return view;
}

//Get goal data from internal storage if goal data has been set before (if it exists in storage)
public void initializeGoalData() {
    Goal goal = WeighInLab.get(getActivity()).getGoal();
    if (goal == null) {
        mWeightValue.setText("");
        mDateValue.setText("");
    } else {
        mWeightValue.setText(Float.toString(goal.getWeight()) + " KG");
        mWeightValue.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_2));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(goal.getDate());
        mDateValue.setText(dateString);
        if (goal.isLoose()) {
            goal_type_toggle.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            goal_type_toggle.setChecked(true);
        }
    }


}

//Show datepicker using a datepickerfragment see DatePickerFragment
private void showDatePicker() {
    DatePickerFragment dpfragment = new DatePickerFragment();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    args.putInt("month", calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    args.putInt("day", calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dpfragment.setArguments(args);

    dpfragment.setCallBack(ondate);
    dpfragment.show(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFragmentManager(), null);
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        SELECTED_DATE = cal.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(SELECTED_DATE);
        mDateValue.setText(dateString);
        didSetDate = true;
        enableSaveIfDataEntered();
    }
};

//Show weight editor as a dialog
public void showWeightEditor() {
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
    d.setTitle("Goal weight");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.weight_picker_dialog);
    Button button_cancel = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
    Button button_set = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button_set);
    final NumberPicker np_constant = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_constant);
    final NumberPicker np_decimal = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_decimal);
    TextView mDialogText = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.weight_edit_dialog_text);
    mDialogText.setText("Enter your goal weight");

    //Config numberpicker for constant
    np_constant.setMaxValue(100); // max value 100
    np_constant.setMinValue(0);   // min value 0
    np_constant.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np_constant.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldValb, int newValb) {
            selectedConstant = picker.getValue();
        }

    });

    final String[] decimals = {".0", ".1", ".2", ".3", ".4", ".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"};
    //Config numberpicker for decimals
    np_decimal.setMaxValue(decimals.length - 1); // max value 100
    np_decimal.setMinValue(0);   // min value 0
    np_decimal.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np_decimal.setDisplayedValues(decimals);
    np_decimal.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldValb, int newValb) {
            int index = picker.getValue();
            String val = decimals[index];
            SELECTED_WEIGHT = Float.parseFloat(val);

        }

    });

    button_set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Float tempfloat = new Float(selectedConstant);
            convertedFloat = tempfloat + SELECTED_WEIGHT;
            String s = Float.toString(convertedFloat);
            mWeightValue.setText(s + " KG");
            ENTERED_WEIGHT = convertedFloat;
            mWeightValue.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_2));
            didSetWeight = true;
            enableSaveIfDataEntered();
            d.dismiss();
        }
    });

    button_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d.dismiss();
        }
    });

    if (didSetWeight) {
        np_constant.setValue(selectedConstant);
        String s = Float.toString(SELECTED_WEIGHT);
        int index = Arrays.asList(decimals).indexOf(s);
        np_decimal.setValue(index);

    }
    d.show();


}

//Enable save button if any data was entered
public void enableSaveIfDataEntered() {

    if (didSetDate && didSetWeight) {
        mSaveButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mSaveButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    getActivity().setTitle("Goal weight");
}




}
```

and this is my DatePickerFragment code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
private int year, month, day;

public DatePickerFragment() {

}

public void setCallBack(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate) {
    ondateSet = ondate;
}

@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    year = args.getInt("year");
    month = args.getInt("month");
    day = args.getInt("day");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
}

}
```

Comment: can you try this ? http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-dialogfragment-confuses-part-2/

Comment: this is very simple to manage loded data take a int a=0; if data or you have data then assigne a=1; else a=0; when ever your orintation change then pass same method or make a condition if(a==1) { then this }else {// Do something}

Comment: @amitsharma I don't quite understand what you mean hear, can you ellaborate?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos It's not quite related to my problem, thx anyways

Comment: Just to clarify, so you have `Fragment1` in the back stack behind the `DatePickerFragment`

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if DatePickerFragment is added to back stack since I do this: "dpfragment.show(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFragmentManager(), null);" But the DatePickerFragment is shown upon GoalFragment, GoalFragment is where I trigger the DatePickerFragment to show, but I don't replace or add DatePickerFragment.

Comment: @Fredrik Ståhl Poor Question that is by no buddy interest in your question. these are the basics of android or c,c++ .

Comment: @amitsharma I can't help it if I don't understand your code or explanation. That's why I'm asking you to ellaborate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can prevent your `Activity` from reloading and in turn reload your fragment by setting the following `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" Activity Flags` in you `manifest.xml`

If you do this and you want to change any of your view parameters you can still do so by **overriding** the `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`

This is for example that *whatsapp* does in its chat view:
When you are writing a message and then rotate the screen it keeps you text 
in the `EditTextView` and it doesn't lose focus from it.

Comment: This is not an option for me at the moment since I'm already handling configuration changes in all my other fragments and my mainactivity. Isn't this bad practice anyway?

Comment: No its definitely not  a bad practice, you need to reload if you have different view or view configuration for this activity or the fragment inside it. For example if you have a fragment in the portrait mode, then you have 2 fragments in the landscape, so you have to change the view of you activity and supply new data for your new fragment

Comment: Do you mean that If I change my configuration settings to: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize", then I have to do this: " you need to reload if you have different view or view configuration for this activity or the fragment inside it. For example if you have a fragment in the portrait mode, then you have 2 fragments in the landscape, so you have to change the view of you activity and supply new data for your new fragment" ? Sounds like even more work.

Comment: No, if you set  ` android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` flags you don't have to save your state.
If you don't you use the default behavior which is saving your instance and then resuming with you saved instance and recreating everything from scratch
So the flags way works cause you don't need to save anything everything is in its state.

Comment: Alright I understand. I looked it up quickly and I realized one con with this is if I'm using different layouts for portait and landscape mode, which I have. How do I go about this?

Comment: Alright, that made it much more clear. I can't wait to try this out when I get home. Thanks alot for your response. I'm just a bit depressed over how much time I've put on handling configuration changes in my app, hopefully that knowledge will come to use in future projects. As I stumbled upon several articles about this.. it seems like android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" will often be fully viable and not bad practice. Thanks again.

Comment: I hear you man, i used to do the same too, but was curious about how IOS handle it so that got me searching. Hope it works for you

Comment: Hey @Fredrik Ståhl , what happened, did you try it out?

Comment: I tried it out and it solved my problems. I'm refactoring my whole app atm. Thanks alot man!

Comment: Nice work man, you are welcome. I struggled too with this before i discovered it. Can you mark it as a right answer so others can benefit form the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because while you change orientation onCreate method is called again. So, In this case you have to override the methods
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState).

You have to save data in bundle in savedInstanceState and 
receive data in RestoreInstanceState method.

Comment: I realized I haven't pushed my code to remote yet so the code is not updated. I have overridden the method "onSaveInstanceState" in GoalFragment, I will update it when I get home from work. Anyways, the problem is not in the goalfragment since it will restore the data on orientation change. But the problem is when I have the datepickerfragment created and visible and rotate the phone, GoalFragment is unable to restore the data.